# How to print of multiple slides on an A4 page without page margins?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

When you print MS Powerpoint slides on an A4 paper,it is printed in such a way a large white space is left. Printing 4 slides is possible on an A4 paper, but I think I can go for 6 slides per page if I remove the white space.(as seen on the print preview) Does anyone know how to do it? Printing of more slides per page is economical because we can save the no of pages and the cost per extra slides printed on multiple pages. Please help

[image: Print preview of the 6 slides per page using microsoft powerpoint 2013]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is actually a question for SuperUser rather than StackOverflow, but the quick answer is to do one of two things:

1) Print SLIDES, not handouts, but set your printer driver to print multiple pages per sheet of paper.  Many printer drivers permit this.

2) Save the presentation as a PDF, open the PDF in Acrobat or Reader and print from there (it allows you to print multiple pages per sheet w/o needing the printer driver to support it).

Comment: The key here is to defer to the printer driver.  I never considered this before.  Works perfectly (if your printer driver can do it).

Comment: In the first case, yes.  In the second case, not really.  Adobe Acrobat or Reader both take care of it (w/o needing printer driver support, as mentioned)